# Which CSS lang syntax is best for localized HTML elements?

Tags: html, css, localization, internationalization

I've found the following two references on the web:

- [A](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-css-lang.es.php)
- [B](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp)

So now I'm wondering, if I have an individual tag within my web page which contains, for instance, Japanese text, then is it best to use

```
p:lang(jp)
```

or

```
p[lang="jp"]
```

Which one is best, and is there a difference between these two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[lang]` will just regularly match elements which have a `lang` attribute. `:lang()` on the other hand is special and resolves the applicable language in much more flexible ways. The language of any one element is resolved by:

> a combination of the `lang` attribute, the `<meta>` element, and possibly by information from the protocol (such as HTTP headers). ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Alang))

Meaning any one element inherits its language from those sources; even an element which does not have an explicit `lang` attribute has *a language* and can be selected with `:lang()`.

It further can resolve regional variations, e.g. `:lang(fr)` also applies to elements with the more specific language `fr-be`.

If you want to style elements based *on their language* (as opposed to elements which have a `lang` attribute), you should certainly use `:lang()`.

Comment: +1: It would be interesting to know how `:lang` actually behaves when HTTP headers, meta and lang attribute are all discordant. Is there some kind of priority?

Comment: @Fabrizio I'm sure you could look that up in the spec, but I'd expect the same inheritance model as CSS: HTTP header, document meta tag, specific element attribute; most specific wins, in this order.

Answer (score 2):

As you have posted the links, it is mentioned as the **best way** to style your content by language is `:lang()`.

The `p[lang="jp"]` method of specifying rules is to use an attribute selector that exactly matches the attribute value.

Unlike `:lang()`, this selector will only work for elements which carry a lang attribute.